# Swallowing water by mistake while fasting

Tags: sawm

I was swimming in the pool and swallowed a very little amount of water by mistake, does that affect fasting or spoil it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forgot I am fasting and realized after eat almost a meal](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/forgot-i-am-fasting-and-realized-after-eat-almost-a-meal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

> If a person is fasting and whilst making wudhu, some water enters his throat either by gaggling or washing the nose, then if one remembers he is fasting the fast will break and the Qadhaa of one fast will have to be kept. However, if one doesn’t remember he is fasting, then the fast will not break. (Tahtawi pg.672)

So basically, there are two possible situations:

a) You accidently swallowed water, **and you knew you were fasting** (so you didn't forget you were fasting at the time of swallowing water). If this is the case, then you have to make up for that day.

b) You accidently swallowed water, **but you forgot you were fasting** (that's why you accidently swallowed it in the first place) at the time of swallowing. After swallowing water you realised that you've just swallowed water. If this is the case, your fast is still valid, and you should keep on fasting until Magrib. You don't have to make up your fast in this case, as you've completed it. The following hadith backs this up.

> Sunan Ibn Majah » The Chapters on what has been Narrated Concerning Fasting from Sunan Ibn Majah. It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever forgets that he is fasting and eats or drinks, let him complete his fast, for the One Who fed him and gave him to drink was Allaah.”

So you have to ask yourself if you **knew** you were fasting at the time of accidently swallowing water. If you knew you were fasting, then your fast is not valid. This is an issue of forgetfulness.

I hope that helps. Allah knows best.

Peace be unto you.

Comment: @Truth Seeker: This is only one opinion of the scholars. The topic has more details for it.

Comment: This is not an opinion at all, because this is clear cut evidence from the Sunnah. This is what the Prophet said, so in that case we should follow what he said (SAW). The opinions of the scholars doesn't matter if Muhammad (SAW) already has an opinion, and his opinion applies to the situation. In this case it does.

Comment: Would you please share the Hadith and the naration of that Hadith that present that evidence?

Comment: I already shared the Hadith... It's right there... I did however add the title of the book it was in. Who really cares about the opinion of the scholars when you have clear evidence like this?

Answer (score 0):

This topic is debatable among the scholars and it's more complicated than it seems.

**First**, swimming while fasting is allowed under the condition that you are in a place were there is no mix between men and women.

**Second**, it comes in 2 situations:

1- You are novice and you don't know if you would be able to control taking water to your stomach. Scholars in that situation preferred for you not to swim at all. In that case, if you went to swim and you took water to your stomach. This will ruin your fast. You need to make it up.

2- You know that you would be able to control the water not to come through to your stomach. You are allowed to swim and there is no issue under that condition. In that case, if you took water by mistake, although you know that you would be able to control there is 2 views among the major scholars:

- It ruins your fast for Maliki, Shafi and Hanifi.
- It's should be ok and it would not ruin fast for that small sip and this is Hanbali opinion.

**Finally, personal opinion:**

Personally (This my own personal opinion. Please refer to the links below for details and ruling), I think it's ok to continue your fast and it shouldn't ruin your fast as the prophet (PBUH) said:

> On the authority of Ibn Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said:
>   Verily Allah has pardoned [or been lenient with] for me my ummah: their mistakes, their forgetfulness, and that which they have been forced to do under duress. A hasan hadeeth related by Ibn Majah, and al-Bayhaqee and others.
>
> عَنْ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ عَنْهُمَا أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه و سلم قَالَ: "إنَّ اللَّهَ تَجَاوَزَ لِي عَنْ أُمَّتِي الْخَطَأَ وَالنِّسْيَانَ وَمَا اسْتُكْرِهُوا عَلَيْهِ" .
>   حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ، رَوَاهُ ابْنُ مَاجَهْ [رقم:2045]، وَالْبَيْهَقِيّ ["السنن" 7 ].

And in your case, you didn't intentionally drink the water and if you know how to swim and know how to control the water not to come to your stomach that should be ok.

**References:**

- http://www.sunnah.com/nawawi40/39
- http://islamqa.info/en/65734
- http://islamqa.info/en/39232
- http://islamqa.info/en/66242

Answer (score -1):

Intention is the Key :

> And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but
>   [only for] what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and
>   Merciful. 33:5

IMHO, fast another day or not should be a matter of choice.

With Peace

Comment: So if it wasn't in my intention to swallow because I was thirsty, then my fasting would be correct.